# Model deployment in Azure ML

Tags: python, azure-web-app-service, web-deployment, azure-machine-learning-service

I am a beginner in the Azure. I am using this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-and-where?tabs=python of setting a dummy script for a local web service but many errors are coming up. It is strange because I am using an h5 file (model involving Keras and tensor flow) in place of onxx file. I used the code

```
from azureml.core import Environment
from azureml.core.model import InferenceConfig

env = Environment(name="myenv")
conda_dep = CondaDependencies()
conda_dep.add_conda_package("tensorflow")
conda_dep.add_conda_package("pip")
conda_dep.add_pip_package("azureml-core")
conda_dep.add_pip_package("azureml-contrib-services")
env.python.conda_dependencies=conda_dep
inference_config = InferenceConfig(
    environment=env,
    source_directory="./source_dir",
    entry_script="./echo_score.py",
)
```

There is a Error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pickle (from -r /azureml-environment-setup/condaenv.4f206b3i.requirements.txt (line 5)) (from versions: none)
```

I have tried many times and getting error. Can anyone help.
My azureml core is 1.34.0 and python version 3.8.11.I am also not sure if it is a pickle protocol error. Pickle version in my system is 4.

Comment: There is no package on PyPI named `azureml.contrib` I guess you should try `azureml-contrib-services`.

Comment: Thanks. But again different error is coming.